# Apply different function to different rows in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to apply diff functions to each row in the dataframe based on which category it is in.

```
def weigh_by_education(row):
    if education_income.education_level == 'College':
        return row / 1013
    if education_income.education_level == 'Doctorate':
        return row / 451
    if education_income.education_level == 'Graduate':
        return row / 3128
    if education_income.education_level == 'High School':
        return row / 2013
    if education_income.education_level == 'Post-Graduate':
        return row / 516
    if education_income.education_level == 'Uneducated':
        return row / 1487
    else:
        return row / 1519
```

Heres my function. - I applied it to my dataframe to try to create a new column called percent -> the number of users in each education_level weighted by the total number of people in that respective category.

`education_income['percent'] = education_income['user_id'].apply(lambda row: weigh_by_education(row))`

However each time it throws a `ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`

My original dataframe is grouped by columns: education_level, income_category. In the values column is the user counts. I want to weigh the user counts by the total number of people in each education_level category. What can I do?

Comment: You apply your function on 'user_id' column by this education_income['user_id']. Is this what you really want?

Answer (score 1):

You might wanna use `numpy.select`

```
conditions = [
    df.education_level == 'College',
    df.education_level == 'Doctorate'
]

values = [
    df.some_column / 1013,
    df.some_column / 451
]

df['percent'] = np.select(conditions, values)
```